# How to change the terminal that launches Neovim?

Tags: neovim, terminal

When I double click a text file, the file is opened with Neovim in an `xfce4-terminal`.

How to change `xfce4-terminal` to `kitty`?

I tried to uninstall `xfce4-terminal` and then `ln -s /usr/bin/kitty /usr/local/bin/xfce4-terminal` to use a fake `xfce4-terminal`, but it doesn't work, nothing happens when double clicking on the file.

I did set `kitty` as the default terminal in "system default application settings", also did `chsh -s /usr/bin/fish`, but it still ask for `xfce4-terminal`.

Possible to change it? I'm on Fedora XFCE.

Comment: This might be better answered on [unix.se]?